# inscrutable behaviour of date in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a variable which has some future date(for example I have taken 30 days after date here), I want to have a conditional statement based on if this future date is 10 days advanced, I was trying following code, but it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong here?

```
> future_date = Date.today + 30.day
 => Wed, 16 Jul 2014
> future_date - Date.today > 10.day
 => false      # Shouldn't this has been true
```

Comment: (future_date - Date.today).to_i > 10.day

Comment: that also doesn't work as `(future_date - Date.today).to_i` is 30 which `10.day.to_i` is 864000.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it should be `(future_date - Date.today).days > 10.days`

Comment: (future_date-Date.today).to_i is not 30 but 2592000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

future_date - Date.today will always give you an answer in days (30)

You can see this by

```
future_date - Date.today
=> 30
```

So you can do...

```
future_date - Date.today > 10
```

And that will work fine.

10.days converts the interval into seconds: 864_000 (number of seconds in ten days) and 30 is not greater than 864_000!